# Parsear link header en golang

Tags: go, http

Quiero hacer un request en `Go` a un API pero las respuestas vienen paginadas así que tengo que recorrerlas.

La paginación viene el el `header` en el elemento `link`, algo parecido a esto:

```
<page=3>; rel="next",<page=1>; rel="prev";<page=5>; rel="last"
```

Estaba intentando resolverlo con expresiones regulares y con `Splits` pero en ambos casos no lo logré.

El request lo estoy haciendo con la librería http, así:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
```

y el `Header.link` lo obtengo así:

```
resp.Header.Get("link")
```

y el resultado es el string que puse arriba.

**Pregunta**

¿Cómo obtengo la última página? ¿Y las demás?

En el mundo de javascript tenemos [parse-link-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-link-header) así que puede que también haya algo parecido en `Go`.

Comment: Y cual es la especificación de formato de la API para ese endpoint?

Answer (score 3):

Encontré esta pequeña librería [linkheader](https://github.com/TomNomNom/linkheader) para go, en todo caso puedes ver como fue implementada aquí [main.go](https://github.com/tomnomnom/linkheader/blob/master/main.go), son solo 120 lineas pero veo que solo utilizan `split` ya que la estructura de *link header* es bastante simple.  Los regex siempre traen problemas.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/tomnomnom/linkheader"
)

func ExampleParse() {
    header := "<https://api.github.com/user/58276/repos?page=2>; rel=\"next\"," +
        "<https://api.github.com/user/58276/repos?page=2>; rel=\"last\""
    links := linkheader.Parse(header)

    for _, link := range links {
        fmt.Printf("URL: %s; Rel: %s\n", link.URL, link.Rel)
    }

    // Output:
    // URL: https://api.github.com/user/58276/repos?page=2; Rel: next
    // URL: https://api.github.com/user/58276/repos?page=2; Rel: last
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo he solucionado utilizando la librería standard de go

```
var b strings.Builder
b.WriteString(urlERP)
b.WriteString(query)
b.WriteString(subQuery1)
b.WriteString(inicioQuery)
b.WriteString(subQuery2)
b.WriteString(finalQuery)
res, err := http.Get(url.QueryEscape(b.String()))
```

necesitas utilizas strings.Builder para ir concatenando y ya que tengas la cadena codificas la URL utlizando url.QueryEscape()